# maximum height/rows and set scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**I have my table in my html php file inside my  i want it to be set the max height and if it reach the max and want to add more it will be scrollable how is this possible? this is for my project thanks**

i want this to be scrollable after 500px reached

```html
<div class="container" style="max-height: 500px;width:600px;height:500px border:1px solid black">
<div class="panel panel-default" style= "max-height: 500px;">
    <div class="panel-heading" align="center">
        <img src="or.png" alt="or" style="width:200px;height:40px;">
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" style= "max-height: 500px;">         
  <table class="table">

  <tr>

<th><FONT color="CB7F16">Foodname</FONT></th>
<th><FONT color="CB7F16">Quantity</FONT></th>

<tr>

<?php

while($food=mysql_fetch_assoc($list)) {

  echo"<tr>";
  
  echo"<td><FONT color='FA9404'>".$food['food']."</FONT></td>";
  echo"<td><FONT color='FA9404'>".$food['quantity']."</FONT></td>";
  
  echo"</tr>";
  
}

?>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><a class="btn" href="acceptorder.php">Accept</a></td>
  </tr>
  
  </table>
  </div> 
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow-y:auto;` to your respective div.

Comment: hey buddy im sorry im new here... i will add this code in style?

Comment: Kamar M oww men it works but 1 thing needs to have solution... my heading scrolling too i want my panel head to fix at top while the body has scroll

Comment: just add overflow-y:auto; to your body panel not for entire section div